# Calculate xarray dataarray from coordinate labels

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have an DataArray with two variables (meteorological data) over time,y,x coordinates. The x and y coordinates are in a projected coordinate system (EPSG:3035) and aligned so that each cell covers pretty much exactly a standard cell of the [1km LAEA reference grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_grid)

I want to prepare the data for further use in Pandas and/or database tables, so I want to add the LAEA Gridcell Number/Label which can be calculated from x and y directly via the following (pseudo) function

```py
def func(cell):
    return r'1km{}{}'.format(int(cell['y']/1000), int(cell['x']/1000))      # e.g. 1kmN2782E4850
```

But as far as I can see there seems to be no possibility, to apply this function to a DataArray or DataSet in a way so that I have access to these coordinate variables (at least `.apply_ufunc()` wasn't really working for me.

I am able to calc this on Pandas later on, but some of my datasets consists of 60 up to 120 Mio. Cells/Rows/datasets and pandas (even with Numba) seems to have troubles with that amount. On the xarray I am able to process this on 32 Cores via Dask.

I would be grateful on any advice on how to get this working.

EDIT: Some more insights of the data I`m working with:

This one is quite the largest with 500 Mio cells, but I am able to downsample this to squarekilometer resolution which ends up with about 160 Mio. cells

[image: Xarray "vci" with monthly Vegetation Condition Indices over some decades]

If the dataset is small enough, I am able to export it as a pandas dataframe and calculate there, but thats slow and not very robust as the kernel is crashing quite often

[image: same calc in pandas]

Comment: could you provide some example data or show how your dataarray looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can apply your function:

```py
import xarray as xr

# ufunc
def func(x, y):
    #print(y)
     return r'1km{}{}'.format(int(y), int(x))

# test data
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("rasm")

xr.apply_ufunc(
    func, 
    ds.x,
    ds.y,
    vectorize=True,
)
```

Note that you don't have to list `input_core_dims` in your case.

Also, since your function isn't vectorized, you need to set `vectorized=True`:

> vectorize : bool, optional
> If True, then assume `func` only takes arrays defined over core
> dimensions as input and vectorize it automatically with
> :py:func:`numpy.vectorize`. This option exists for convenience, but is
> almost always slower than supplying a pre-vectorized function.
> Using this option requires NumPy version 1.12 or newer.

Using `vectorized` might not be the most performant option as it is essentially just looping, but if you have your data in chunks and use `dask`, it might be good enough.

If not, you could look into creating a vectorized function with e.g. numba that would speed things up surely.

More info can be found in the [xarray tutorial on applying ufuncs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html#Vectorization-with-np.vectorize)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Works blazing fast. The DataSet gets so large now, I am even not able to overhand it as a pd DataFrame but thats another story and I think I'll just stick with xray as long as possible. P.S: perhaps edit your answer for others as `df_vci` is a Pandas dataframe in my example whereas the corresponding Xray just identifies as `vci`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply_ufunc` in an [unvectorised way](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html):

```
def func(x, y):
    return f'1km{int(y/1000)}{int(x/1000)}'  # e.g. 1kmN2782E4850

xr.apply_ufunc(
    func, # first the function
    x.x,  # now arguments in the order expected by 'func'
    x.y
    )
```

Comment: that results in `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` ... do I have to do something like `reset_index()` first? Is there any possibility to access the coordinates directly without reseting the index first?

Comment: @JürgenZornig without seeing what your xarray looks like I can't tell you how to fix that error - it looks like it's applying the function to an entire series (column) instead of each individual value.

Comment: I added some screenshots above

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to provide useful hints, unfortunately this didn't work and I wasn't able to sort it out myself, whereas @Val 's answer provided a working code example plus an explanation and useful links. I upvote your answers as much as possible, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @jürgenzornig no worries - yeah I forgot to add the vectorised=True arg.